# What is different between the implementation of deconvolution with fft and the deconv function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I've got stuck in this code:

```
function [ y ] = mydeconv( c,x )
    lx=length(x);
    lc=length(c);
    %lt=lx+lc;
    c=[c zeros(1,lx)];
    x=[x zeros(1,lc)];
    y = ifft(real((fft(c)) ./(fft(x))));
end
```

and the result is:

```
mydeconv([1 2 3 3 2 1],[1 1 1])
ans =
Column 1
            NaN + 0.000000000000000i
Column 2
            NaN +               NaNi
Column 3
            NaN +               NaNi
Column 4
            NaN + 0.000000000000000i
Column 5
            NaN +               NaNi
Column 6
            NaN +               NaNi
Column 7
            NaN + 0.000000000000000i
Column 8
            NaN +               NaNi
Column 9
            NaN +               NaNi
```

and the result of `deconv` function simply is:

```
deconv([1 2 3 3 2 1],[1 1 1])
ans =
 1     1     1     1
```

In principle it should work, I can't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: why are you taking the `real` value after one of the FFTs?

Comment: actually ,at first I didn't but I read some where that,this will correct the answer,but ddin't,it doesn't give the correct answer without real though.

Answer (score 2):

Since the padded vector `x` has a length that is a multiple of the original, you end up with zeros in the frequency domain of `fft(x)`. You can avoid this by choosing a different (longer) length when such zeros are observed:

```
function [ y ] = mydeconv( c,x )
  lx=length(x);
  lc=length(c);
  if (lc >= lx)
    lt = lc;
    while (1)
      xpadded = [x zeros(1,lt-length(x))];
      Xf = fft(xpadded);
      if (min(abs(Xf)) > 0)
        break;
      end
      lt = lt + 1;
    end
    cpadded = [c zeros(1,lt-length(c))];
    Cf = fft(cpadded);
    y = real(ifft(Cf ./ Xf));
    y = y(1:lc-lx+1);
  else
    y = [];
  end
end
```

Comment: how can I know if this two vector even have deconvolution?

Comment: Provided the length of `c` is at least that of `x` and that neither `x` or `c` is strictly 0 everywhere, then there is a `y` which by the convolution theorem would be such that `conv(x,y) = c`, whereas `c = ifft(fft(xpadded) .* fft(ypadded))`. Then it's simply a basic algebra to get that the converse `ypadded = ifft(fft(c) ./ fft(xpadded))` similarly exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

Firstly, you should take `real` part of the IFFT output, not of individual FFTs.

Secondly, you should protect against zero-divide-by-zero cases, which are resulting in `NaN` in your example.

You can implement both of the above, by modifying the line computing `y` as follows:

```
y = real(ifft((eps+fft(c)) ./ (eps+fft(x))));
```

Note that `eps` is a small positive number to protect against zero-divide-by-zero cases. With this, the output is:

```
disp(y)
% 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much,that was so pithy.

Comment: just one more question,how can I remove the extra zeros after decimal point?

Comment: If you know for sure that `c = conv(x, y)`, then you could simply select the first `length(c) - length(x) + 1` elements of `y`. In the general case, you could choose the first few elements that contain more than 99% of the total energy of the sequence.

Comment: Note that if any of the FFT values were to be equal to `-eps` you'd be right back with the same problem of divide-by-zero.

Comment: @SleuthEye: Fair enough. If that is an issue, the computation can be modified slightly to prevent all divide-by-zeros: `y = real(ifft((fft(c).*conj(fft(x))+eps) ./ (eps+abs(fft(x)).^2)));`.